# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in c# SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am a beginner in C#.
I have a textbox and a button.

When i click the button it displays datetime in textbox.

```
protected void btnStartTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSrvStartTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
}
```

Now problem is when i update my page i'm getting an error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here is my sqlCommand Syntax:

```
SelectCmd.Parameters.Add("@servStartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(LblSrvEndTime.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

Comment: Again, what page you are trying to update?

Comment: This is not a problem with SQL - it's a problem with the format in the `ParseExact` method. The error message states that the format does not match the input. Perhaps somewhere between the button click and the execution of the SQL command, the value gets changed

Comment: @GordonLinoff that would be a good advice if the OP would pass a string literal to SQL Server, however the OP is passing an instance of `DateTime`, and c#'s `DateTime` maps directly to SQL Server's `DateTime`/`DateTime2` and `Date`...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DateTime.ParseExact(LblSrvEndTime.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I tried that one but it shows error: the name CultureInfo doesn't exit in the current context

Comment: @DarshanPatni  You're probably missing a "using namespace System.Globalization;"

Comment: @DarshanPatni . Did you get the same error or  not work for your problem ?

Comment: I got the solution. I try different method and it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your valuable time.
I got the solution:

txtSrvStartTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");

```
    SqlConnection connsv = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    connsv.Open();
    string SelectQuery = @"UPDATE [Table_Name] SET 
                            [Service Start Time]=@servStartTime
                            WHERE [ID]=@shipnum";

    SqlCommand SelectCmd = new SqlCommand(SelectQuery, connsv);
    SelectCmd.Parameters.Add("@servStartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtSrvStartTime.Text;
    SelectCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connsv.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem with a parsing of string to Date. But nothing helped. The issue was in Microsoft date and time settings. Try to play with it, because on the different machines, depends of this setting, we had or didn`t have such parsing problems with the same culture! Hope it will help someone.